# $this->Auth->user(); only id instead whole array

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm struggling with the auth-componentent in CakePHP 2.x
The Book says [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)  (last entry at the bottom) that

```
$this->Auth->user();
```

returns all user data if parameter is null.

```
"$key (string) – The user data key you want to fetch. 
If null, all user data will be returned."
```

But if I echo out `$u`

```
$u = $this->Auth->user();
```

Then only the user id is displayed. I expected the whole user array. Any ideas?

Comment: What does var_dump($this->Auth->user()); say?

Comment: You mean like `$u = $this->Auth`?

Comment: var_dump($this->Auth->user()); says string(2) "21". It's the id, not the array.

Comment: so `user()` returns `id` not array

Comment: $u = $this->Auth is not working. It' says Error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64225280 bytes)

Comment: Royal Bg, yes, my words. Is the book saying the wrong thing? Can't believe that...

Comment: No the book is correct, your code is incorrect. For some reason you store the array too flat. I suspect your login code to be wrong.

Comment: Thank you mark, you are right. I changed the login code, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Auth->user();
```

return value is array, so if you want just print whole content for debug, try

```
$u = $this->Auth->user();
var_dump($u);
```

or

```
print_r($u);
```

Comment: I know that. I say: $this->Auth->user(); returns the id instead the whole user array as described in the book.

Answer (score 0):

`$u = $this->Auth->user();`

returns an associative array, you access fields by keys in the table, e.g

```
echo $u['username']; 
echo $u['email'];
```

Comment: You have not understood my problem. I know that it should return an associative array, BUT IT DON'T!!! Read my question again...

Comment: @FishWave See my comment above. Fix your code - especially around your login. Then it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

$u = $this->Auth->user();

```
Yes you are trying echo $u;
```

Insted of this try below

```
vardump($u); or print_r($u);
```

let me now if that helpful to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Mark (DerEuroMark) expected in the comment, my login script was wrong. For some reason I stored the array too flat. **The login code was wrong**. I fixed the login code (respectively I wrote it from scatch and now everything works fine.
**Thank you anyway for all the replies.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..........
pr($this->Auth->user());

Answer (score -1):

```
 $this->Auth->user();
```

return data from users table, you should use

```
 $id= $this->Auth->user('id');
```

To fetch id

Comment: He wants to fetch all the data, not only `id`.

Comment: When i do $this->Auth->user('id') then I get Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Hash::get() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/xxx/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php on line 656 and defined [CORE/Cake/Utility/Hash.php, line 43]